# A quick way to squeeze multiple times in PytTorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Is there any efficient way to to squeeze (unsqueeze) multiple times in pytorch tensors?

For example a tensor **a** has shape: [4,1,1,2],

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], dtype=torch.float32)
a = a.reshape(4,1,1,2)
print(a.shape)

torch.Size([4, 1, 1, 2])
```

I would like to squeeze **a** to [4, 2] but without squeezing it twice manually, e.g.,

```
a1 = a.squeeze(1).squeeze(1)
print(a1.shape)
torch.Size([4, 2])
```

Is there any way that I don't have to write `(un)squeeze(1)` twice/multiple times. Thanks

Comment: `unsqueeze` only takes a number, not a tuple.  But you already know how to add multiple size 1 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `a.squeeze(1)`. Just `a.squeeze()` will give you the desired result.

Comment: or `a.squeeze((1,2))`.  Read the docs. `dims` can be none, a number or a tuple.   The result is a `view`, or whatever torch's equivalent, so repeated calls to `squeeze` is not in-efficient (unless you are counting key strokes).

Comment: WoW. that is clever. Thank you so much, @jared